# How can I change the FlatButton ripple position?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In Material-UI, The FlatButton, when is clicked, it will animate a ripple, ripple will start where you click the point, how can I change the ripple will start in the FlatButton center?
example: in the below picture, the ripple started from the top right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NFCH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the undocumented `centerRipple` property (boolean) on the FlatButton:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dymkau2b/1/

```
<FlatButton centerRipple label="Center Ripple" />
```

(The `={true}` is implicit in JSX)